# How to work with a isometric / orthogonal view in Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, button, kivy, orthogonal

The image below is a GridLayout 10 x 10 with buttons.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZsJI.png]

I'd like to create the same Grid but in an **isometric / orthogonal 2d view**.

It means that every button, instead of being a square, it might be like a Rhombus, as the image below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: I've only come across one example of something like this so far. It's hexagons instead of rhombus's, but hopefully it will help you. In case the link breaks, it's a video titled "The art of writing wargames in Python with Kivy (Dorian Pula)
" on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hM9qbW8-roE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can actually do a 3D rotation on kivy UIX widgets, but you can do 2D rotations, and scaling. Here is an example of an `App` that does it in the `build()` method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PushMatrix, Rotate, Scale, PopMatrix
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import numpy as np


def matrixToNumpy(mat):
    a = []
    for i in range(4):
        b = []
        for j in range(4):
            b.append(mat[i*4+j])
        a.append(b)
    npmat = np.mat(a)
    return npmat


class MyButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.parent.touched:
            self.parent.touched = True
            if self.parent.mat is None:
                scale = matrixToNumpy(self.parent.sca.matrix)
                rotate = matrixToNumpy(self.parent.rot.matrix)
                self.parent.mat = np.matmul(rotate, scale)
                self.parent.inv_mat = self.parent.mat.I
            npTouch = np.mat([touch.x, touch.y, 0, 1.0])
            convTouch = np.matmul(npTouch, self.parent.inv_mat)
            touch.x = convTouch[0,0]
            touch.y = convTouch[0,1]
        return super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.parent.touched = False
        return super(MyButton, self).on_touch_up(touch)


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    touched = BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mat = None
        self.inv_mat = None


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = MyGridLayout(cols=10)
        with layout.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            layout.sca = Scale(1.0, 0.5, 1.0)
            layout.rot = Rotate(angle=45, axis=(0,0,1), origin=(400,300,0))
        with layout.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()
        for i in range (1, 101):
            layout.add_widget(MyButton(text=str(i)))
        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

I suspect that with clever application of those two `kivy.graphics.context_instructions`, you can simulate what you want. The `PushMatrix()` and `PopMatrix()` confine the effects of the `Scale` and `Rotate` to just the `MyGridLayout`. You should be able to adjust these values using the `layout.sca` and `layout.rot` references.

I noticed after my original answer that the `Buttons` looked good, but no longer worked. I added a bunch of code to address that issue. All the `numpy` matrix stuff is just to get the mouse press position into the same coordinates as the `MyGridLayout`. Unfortunately, applying `Canvas` scaling and rotations isn't automatically taken into account by the Kivy events, so the additional code is necessary.

Here is what it looks like:
[image: This is the resulting button array]

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner with Kivy, could you please complete your code with the whole "from kivy" imports?

Comment: A couple things to keep in mind. First, this will only work with `MyGridLayout` containing `MyButton` instances (with no other layouts in between). Second, if you change the `Rotate` or `Scale` values dynamically, you need to set the `self.mat` to `None` in the `MyGridLayout` instance to trigger recalculation of the matrices.

Comment: actually you can do 3D rotations, but i would stay this is still a more convenient solution, especially as in this kind of games, you usually want isometric 3D (as the image shows) sometime called 2.5D, rather than full 3D.

Comment: @Tshirtman, I've seen 3D rotation of objects (like the MonkeyHead example), but not of GUI elements. I have attempted 3D rotations of GUI elements, but I could never get it to work. If you have a pointer on how to do it, I would love to see it.

Comment: i have this (flawed) experiment https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/aab72d0fb05601b0294b5a5882270d9f, because i suck at matrix math i believe, and there are more complex things like https://github.com/kpiorno/kivy3dgui

Comment: @Tshirtman, wish I had found that sooner. Looks like that `kivy3dgui` does exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @RogérioDec, the `kivy3dgui` that @Tshirtman mentions looks like what you are looking for. It does real 3D with kivy gui elements. If you are putting together some sort of 3D game, I think that would work better for you than my answer.

Comment: I didn't use it, but it might have limitations for what you want to do, last time i checked some decisions were hardcoded, I do think your solution is neat, especially if you want 2.5D.